# How can get the item localized/unlocalized info on Component/Page selection

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a custom button created in the ribbon of tridion.

If an item either Component/Page has been selected i need to get the info whether the item is localized or not. Based on that custom button will be enabled/disabled.

For getting the tcmid of the selected component/page i am currently writing as

selection.getItem(0); in my javascript.

Similarly, how can i get the localized info of the selected item(Component/Page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the isLocalized method of the item:

```js
var itemUri = selection.getItem(0);
var item = $models.getItem(itemUri);
if (item.isLocalized())
{
   // Do your magic here
}
```

I've left out the error handling and potential loading of the item, for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

The Properties and Methods of the UI JavaScript Objects can be found in the [SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 GUI Extension API](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/GUI%20Extension%20API_tcm89-20010.zip) documentation which you can find on http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion

Just check in the `Tridion.ContentManager` Namespace and you will find things like `Component.getInfo()` and `Component.getBlueprintHierarchy()` from which you can extract this kind of information.

Comment: Shouldn't the `isLocalized` provide that information directly?

Comment: I have tried selection.isLocalized and selection.getItem.isLocalized; but both of them are returning undefined on component/page selection

Comment: @Bart, what, a new documentation site? Oh wait, it's TridionWorld.

Comment: I have gone through the API's. I didnt find exactly the one which returns whether the item is localized or not on selection. Is there any other way(indirect) to identify whether the selected item is localized or not. Could you please suggest me.